# Can you end a sentence with 'hence'?

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs, sentence-ends

Pretentiousness/archaism aside, does the sentence

> Any changes that were made have been detailed hence.

make sense? The context would be that the descriptions of changes would be found in the paragraphs following this sentence.

Comment: Carefully look up **all** the meanings of *hence* before interpreting the sentence. It's correct.

Comment: @Kris Whilst it is undoubtedly correct, it is not a fashionable use, and some people may be unclear as to what it means. I would, in that context, use *hereunder*.

Comment: @ws2 It's almost archaic, and archaic is what they use in legalese and bureacratese. Do not use *hereunder,* it is neither here nor there.

Comment: A surprisingly common, and similarly mannered, alternative in academic writing would be "in the sequel". Almost guaranteed to bewilder the unfamiliar reader...

Comment: Your title is at the very least broader than your actual question and possibly at variance to it.  I could add a clause to that sentence (e.g. "detailed hence, with full references to the relevant directives.") and you would still object, according to the text of your question.  Do you object to "The new policy will come into effect 2 months hence"?  If not, your title is wrong.  If yes, your text is at best inaccurate and incomplete.

Comment: Apologies, yes, my title was too broad.

Comment: the question title is fine.

Comment: @Mari-LouA the question in the title simply doesn't match the question in the text.  It's irrelevant and misleading.   Why do that?  It requires clarification before a good answer can be given.  Better to change the title than add to the body of the question (which would not be ambiguous with a relevant title).  Look, Joe Dark has answered the question in the title, not the question in the body.

Comment: @Kris Of the four dictionaries I have now looked in (I don't currently have access to the OED), **not one** has a definition of _hence_ that would cover the usage in this question. Please specify what dictionary and what sense you are referring to that would make it correct to use _hence_ to mean “in the following [text]”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A look at [the three meanings of *hence*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hence), reveal possible meanings of:

1. "As a consequence; for this reason". Not the meaning here, and makes no grammatical sense.
2. "From now" I expect that is the intended meaning, (i.e. "we will detail the changes after this") but the dictionary says it must be "used after a period of time" - i.e. that the period of time must come before 'hence' in the sentence, which is not the case.
3. "From here" (archaic). Again not what is meant.

Therefore I conclude that the word is misused here. You could say "the changes that were made will be detailed a week hence". The writing of "have been detailed" means the detailing occurred in the past, even if it is later in the document (which I assume is what the writer is trying to imply), so that's two reasons 'hence' shouldn't be used.

There are plenty of ways to correctly end a sentence with 'hence'., including the example I gave above and Joe Dark's example.